# How to get Json data on page load OR get url generated from Json data on click event

Tags: java, selenium

I'm testing an existing website and I need to pick up the url of a link and the `href text = "#"`.

If I click on the link, whatever it is opens then displays a perfectly normal URL in the browser, so the website is somehow translating "#" into a proper URL. I have several hundred items, all referenced by "#", but all opening completely different items when you click on them.

I need to know what it is before I click it as I have to be able to handle it opening as a pop up or in a separate window or as a load instruction to office etc. and therefore pass the URL to different bits of code to open, depending on the file extension.

I've tried:

```
teststring = "//div[@class='" + divClass.toString() + "']/div[2]/a";    
LesTestString = driver.findElement(By.xpath(teststring)).getAttribute("href");
```

which returns 'myWebsite.com/my/path/here/#'; and

```
String LessLink = inputhandler.getAttribute("href");
```

which does the same.

when I look at the element in firebug it looks like this:

```
<div class="reference span5 ">
<a class="name math-formula" href="#"> 1.1 Lesson Player </a>
```

Any suggestions?

Added Information: It would seem that the URL is generated by the browser on click from various bits of information sent in a large Json string.  So this questions should now be either (1) how do you pick up the url generated by the browser onclick, or (2) how do you pick up the Json sent from the server using java /selenium or something that will run in that environment?

Comment: Have you checked if the URL isn't being opened on an `onclick` event?

Comment: Ah, yes it seems to be.  I'll try and catch the header with a HttpURLConnection or similar.  Thank you.

Comment: OK, I give up.  how do I catch the URL from the header I can see in Fiddler?

Comment: I'll improve your question title so you can have better chances of finding help :)